# SQL Server: error not thrown for multiple updates

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have simple procedure to update 2 tables:

```
create procedure p_updatetrans(@id int)
as
    declare @errmsg Nvarchar(200)

    begin tran
        update table1 
        set data = 10 
        where id = @id

        if (@@error <> 0 or @@rowcount = 0)
        begin
            select @errmsg = 'Fail to update table1'
            goto error
        end

        update table2 
        set isUpdate = true 
        where id = @id

        if (@@error <> 0 or @@rowcount = 0)
        begin
            select @errmsg = 'Fail to update table2'
            goto error
        end

        commit tran
        return

error:
     raiserror(@errmsg, 16 ,1)
  rollback tran
```

Why do I get no error when there's no record in table2 to update? If I use NoCount On, I can't get @@rowcount data.

Thanks

Comment: The last line of your `UPDATE` statements should be `WHERE id = @id` - `WHERE` - not `WHEN`......

Comment: If there is no data in table2, then the `UPDATE` statement just doesn't do anything - it will not fail or throw an error - that's by design.

Comment: thanks marc_s, but i have trap there with @@rowcount. So i think there is no record updated, should be go to error section

Comment: Does is still fails if you store the @@variables into custom variables using something like  `select @errorvar = @@error, @rowcountvar = @@rowcount ?`

Comment: Not fail @Gonzalo.- thats why raiserror never show

Comment: when I said "fail" I meant "do you still get the unexpected behaviour of notgetting @@rowcount data as you expected?"